# If statement firing wrong alert

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to fire an alert in success function of ajax call. The problem is that it keeps firing the same alert and doesn't seem to recognize the data string value.

In my example, the alert that keep firing is the `yes` alert. I can see in firebug that the value being returned by php is what I am trying to compare against. I am confused as to why this simple function is not working and need to find solution before I start main coding. I would be grateful if someone could help with this. Many thanks

ajax

```
success: function(data) {
  if (data == 'No Date Set') {
    alert('No');
  }
  else {
    alert('yes');
  }
}
```

php

```
if($ddate =='No Date Set') {
  echo $ddate;
}
```

ajax code snippet

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'niajax.php',
  data: data,
  async: false,
  beforeSend: function() {
    $(".text").show().html('Processing your request...');
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    if (data == 'No Date Set') {
      alert('Date not set');
    }
    else {
      alert('Date set');
    }
  },
  error: function(xhr) {
    $(".text").fadeIn(4000).html('Error occured.please try again').fadeOut(4000);
    //alert("Error occured.please try again");
  },
  complete: function() {},
})
```

Comment: Do a `console.log(data)` before the if statement and check the output in the console.

Comment: what is the dataType value in your ajax?? if it is json. use data.d instead of data.

Comment: @Mehdi Value in console.log is: `No Date Set` Thanks

Comment: @GaganDeep There is no datatype set. Thanks

Comment: please include the entire ajax call function so that we may have a better understanding of the code.

Comment: Possible problem is that a "space" is added when it's returned to you via AJAX. Also, I find it as a good practice to add `exit;` after any return for my AJAX. So in your case `echo $ddate; exit;`

Comment: Sounds weird, can you post a screenshot of your console in the question? @hungrykoala you don't really have to exit, I don't think there is an advantage of exiting.

Comment: @hungrykoala I already tried exit;. No difference.

Comment: than it's better for you to search for string in response:
`if (data.indexOf("No Date Set") == 0)` if you have extra space or new line characters at the end, or you can remove all spaces at the end:
`data = data.replace(/\s*$/, "")`

Comment: You could always just strip away all the spaces to make sure no other characters are appended to your data. `NoDateSet`

Comment: Check the data type of data coming from response, and parse it accordingly in if condition. if you compare values with different data types then it will always returns false even though you have same values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is unclear, but it might be due to a white space, you can `trim` the data returned:

```
success: function(data)
    if (data.trim() == 'No Date Set') {
      alert('Date not set');
    }
    else {
      alert('Date set');
    }
},
```

Comment: I assumed this would remove all the space from the string. Learned something new. :)

Comment: @hungrykoala It would only trim it, so that "   text    " will turn into "text". Glad I helped.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of setting long text use `true` or `false` or create one word `status`.

The above convention can be ambiguous some times and comparison will take some time.